# How can I transfer multiple contacts as defaultFieldValues to new Event in e.force:createRecord?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura

How can I transfer multiple contacts as defaultFieldValues to new Event  in e.force:createRecord?
I tring code like this but it does not work

```
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Event",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        'EventWhoRelations' : [{RelationId: "0030Q000011pIyRQAU", Type: "Contact"},{RelationId: "0030Q000011pIzAQAU", Type: "Contact"}],
        'Subject' : 'Hello' 
    }
});
createRecordEvent.fire();
```

`

Comment: doesn't work is not very descriptive ? can you elaborate?

Comment: It is open new record form but multiple contact field "Name" is empty.